# Updating State React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbGNe.png) represents an object with two ui controls that are stored  as this.state.controls

Initially the statesValue values are set via data that is received prior to componentDidMount and all is good. However updates to the each of the controls  statesValues are sent via an event , which is handled with the following function

```js
const handleValueStateChange = event => {
  
      let controls = Object.entries(this.state.controls);
      for (let cont of controls) {
        let states = cont[1].states;
        if (states) {
          let state = Object.entries(states);  
          for (let [stateId, contUuid] of state) {
            if (contUuid === event.uuid) {
              cont[1].statesValue[stateId] = event.value;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

which updates the values happily, however bearing in mind the updated values that change are a subset of this.state.controls, I have no idea how to use this.setState to update that that has been changed.

thanks in advance for any pointers

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please spend more time developing your question before you ask. Expecting someone to help by going through an image of a huge object is unreasonable. You need to take time to break your question down into the least amount of content to produce your issue. This will help you understand what you're asking, and 9/10 times you will answer your own question before you can ask it. Good luck!

Comment: Using [componentDiDupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) it is possible to update the states after componentDidMount is called.

Comment: @Travis Sorry I am new to both this site and React, so I was trying to give as much information as possible, To make the question more precise ... if using the above function how do I use this.setState to update the changed values of one control given that i am looping over  one control of many

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Object.entries` try destructuring to keep the reference to the objects. 
And have a look at lodash. There are some nice helper functions to iterate over objects like mapValues and mapKeys. So you can keep the object structure and just replace the certain part. Afterwards update the whole state-object with the new one.

```
const handleValueStateChange = event => {
      let {controls} = this.state;
      controls = _.mapValues(controls, (cont) => {
        const states = cont[1].states;
        if (states) {
          _.mapValues(states, (contUuid,stateId) => {  
            if (contUuid === event.uuid) {
              cont[1].statesValue[stateId] = event.value;
            }
          });
        }
        return cont;
      });
      this.setState({controls});
    };
```

Code is not tested but it should work like this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you're updating an object which you've changed from it's original structure (by using `Object.entries`). You can still iterate in the same way however you'll need to update an object that maintains the original structure. Try this:

Make a copy of the `controls` object. Update that object. Replace it in `state`.

```
const handleValueStateChange = event => {
    // copy controls object
    const { controls } = this.state;
    let _controls = Object.entries(controls);
    for (let cont of _controls) {
        let states = cont[1].states;
        if (states) {
            let state = Object.entries(states);  
            for (let [stateId, contUuid] of state) {
                    if (contUuid === event.uuid) {
                        // update controls object
                        controls[cont[0]].statesValue[stateId] = event.value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // replace object in state
    this.setState({controls});
};
```